# Confusion about calculator program

Tags: c

```
int getop(char s[])
{
    int i = 0, c, next;
    /* Skip whitespace */
    while((s[0] = c = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t')
        ;
    s[1] = '\0';    
    /* Not a number but may contain a unary minus. */
    if(!isdigit(c) && enter code herec != '.' && c != '-')
        return c;
    if(c == '-')
    {
        next = getch();
        if(!isdigit(next) && next != '.')
           return c;
        c = next;
    }
    else
        c = getch();    

    while(isdigit(s[++i] = c)) //HERE
            c = getch();
    if(c == '.')                     /* Collect fraction part. */
        while(isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
                        ;
    s[i] = '\0';
    if(c != EOF)
        ungetch(c);
    return NUMBER;
};
```

**what if there is no blank space or tab than what value will s[0] will initialize .......& what is the use of s[1]='\0'**

Answer (score 1):

> **what if there is no blank space or tab than what value will s[0] will intialize**

The following loop will *continue executing* until `getch()` returns a character that's neither a space nor a tab:

```
while((s[0] = c = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t')
    ;
```

> **what is the use of s[1]='\0'**

It converts `s` into a [C string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) of length 1, the only character of which has been read by `getch()`. The `'\0'` is the required NUL-terminator.

Comment: how (c=getchar()) gets EOF in windows bcz my program is not stopping taking inputs even i enter -1(which i think is the EOF value)...help plz

Comment: @torres: When you enter `-1`, your program gets the character `'-'` followed by the character `'1'`. If you want to enter EOF on Windows, press Ctrl+Z (possibly followed by the Enter key).

Comment: @six:neither Ctrl+Z nor Ctrl+Z+enter......so how will be use getchar();
explain plz...

Answer (score 0):

1. If there is no space or tab, you're stuck with an infinite loop.
2. s[1]='\0' is a way of marking the end so functions like strlen()
   know when to stop reading through c strings.  it's called "Null-Terminating" a string: http://chortle.ccsu.edu/assemblytutorial/Chapter-20/ass20_2.html

Comment: the line "while((s[0] = c = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t');"  will keep making calls to getch() until it finds a ' ' or a '\t'.  If this doesn't happen, it will continue calling getch() forever.

Answer (score 0):

```
while((s[0] = c = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t')
```

Read character until its not a tab or space.

```
s[1] = '\0';
```

Convert char array s to a proper string in C format (all strings in c must be terminated with a null byte, which is represented by '\0'.